# How can I declare an object into another class on F#?

Tags: f#

I am totally newbie in F# and I am trying to create an object that contains aonother instance from other class. For me in C# it's quite easy, but in F# I have serious problems to understand it.

Here is my code

```
module Owe

type Owe= class

val Name: string
val Amount: float

new (name, amount) as this =
{
    Name = name
    Amount = amount
}
end
```

And this is the class that I want to instace using the Owe object…. but, I can't invoque the Owe attribute.

```
module Roomate

type Roomate = class

val Name : string
val Owe: module.Owe   //Error!

new(name, owe) as this =
{
   Name = name
   Owe = owe
}
end
```

I reallay apreciate any advice or solution.

Thanks in advance.

Emma.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably getting an error because `module.Owe` is not a correct way of referencing a type from another module. You do not need the `module` keyword here - you just need to give the module name and the class name as in `<module-name>.<class-name>`. In your case, somewhat confusingly, both the module name and the class name are `Owe` so you can write `Owe.Owe`.

Another thing to keep in mind is that, in F#, the order of files matters. This means that you can only reference classes from files that appear earlier in your project.

Finally, I would also add that it is quite common to declare multiple types in one file (and in one module) in F#, so you do not need to move your definitions into separate files. I would also recommend using the lightweitght syntax for declaring classes using implicit constructors:

```
type Owe(name:string, amount:float) = 
  member x.Name = name
  member x.Amount = amount

type Roomate(name:string, owe:Owe) =
  member x.Name = name
  member x.Owe = owe
```

Although in this case, you might not need classes at all and you could probably just use records:

```
type Owe = { Name:string; Amount:float }
type Roomate = { Name:string; Owe:Owe }
```